# Remove Woocommerce category-class-names from Category page markup

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

Every time I place a product in a category, the product gets the category-name as a div-class on the category pages.

If the product is "Curtains" and its in multiple categories like "Bedroom Curtains", "Livingroom Curtains", "Kitchen Curtains"

Then the product html markup will look like this on the category pages:

< div class="product col has-hover type-product post-6672 status-publish first instock **product_cat-bedroom-curtains product_cat-livingroom-curtains product_cat-kitchen-curtains**">

I would like to get rid of this unnecessary code.

Comment: why would you like to remove this classes ? I guess they are applied to give you the ability to apply custom styles by categories

Comment: I have lot of variable products, and some of them are dispayed in 50 category for example. With 50-60 products displayed on a category page its, nearly 100kb of unnecessary code, that I not intend to use for anything.

Comment: have you tried to reach support?